# make footer grow with jquery/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im creating a page where my footer is growing on a certain event.
My problem is to make the footer grow according to how much space i got. 
See my code or jsFiddle. I want the gray footer to grow all the way up to the colored elements with dynamic height (instead of like now, to 20%).
I guess i could count all the elements height above but that doesn't sound like a good solution.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/304/)

```
            <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    body #pagePlaceHolderOuter {
                        background: #FFFFFF;
                        height: 100%;
                        left: 0;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                        body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner {
                            height: 100%;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            max-width: 1000px;
                            min-width: 700px;
                            width: 70%;
                            position: relative;
                        }

                            body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner .div1 {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 100px;
                                background: blue;
                            }

                            body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner .div2 {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 120px;
                                background: green;
                            }

                            body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner .div3 {
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 60px;
                                background: red;
                            }

                            body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner .footer {
                                background: gray;
                                bottom: 0;
                                height: 10%;
                                position: absolute;
                                width: 100%;
                            }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script>
                    $("#btn").click(function () {
                        $('body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner .footer').css('height', '20%');
                    });
                </script>

                <div id="pagePlaceHolderOuter">
                    <div id="pagePlaceHolderInner">
                        <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
                        <div class="div1">I have a dynamic height</div>
                        <div class="div2">I have a dynamic height</div>
                        <div class="div3">I have a dynamic height</div>

                        <div class="footer">Footer</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: these are not dynamic, they are fixed height cause you typed the height of the elements inside the placeholder, if you really want to make it with jQ I think getting the elements height is the only way to do this. You can also move the footer to another wrapper, then get only height of element wrapping the inner divs.

Comment: The footer should be floating always on the bottom of the screen or in the bottom of the page? If the last is your situation you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/siliconball/VJRvZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating the space of *all* the elements before, you can simply calculate the height of the most previous one and find the `offset().top` of that element. Using this approach I calculated the space (you have to make sure in your HTML the footer is directly after the previous element or slightly restructure my jQuery) and essentially you just toggle it between the default value and the default value + the space. [**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/WGCyu/311/)

```
$("#btn").click(function (e) {
    var prev = $('.footer').prev(),
        winHeight = $(window).height(),
        calcTop = $('.footer').height() == Math.round(winHeight / 10) ? 
            (winHeight - prev.offset().top - prev.height()) : "10%";
    $('body #pagePlaceHolderOuter #pagePlaceHolderInner .footer').css({
        'height': calcTop
    });
});
```

On a side note I used CSS transitions to "animate" the change, not jQuery for performance issues and for ease of editablity

If you just want the position to change, not the height, you can do it by toggling the `bottom` value instead. [**Demo of that here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/WGCyu/309/)

Comment: Wow, that's a great solution, thanks a lot man! Kamil suggestion with a wrapper wasn't bad ether